# Category image for each subcategory in megamenu

Tags: magento2, category, megamenu

How can I add an image, like a thumbnail, for each subcategory in the mega menu. i have tried to upload an image in the content section of the category, but it shows in the category view page, and i tried in SW menu to put it in top block, but the block does not show at all. i need to show it in the menu on top of the category column. exactly similar to this example: https://snag.gy/iUE8uK.jpg. i am using magento 2.2.5, this is the website URL: belsuit.com

Answer (score 0):

There are Two way to achieve this :

**1.** you can use third party module like megamenu etc.

**2.** You can achieve this by following steps:

a. Create one category image attribute for menu image like **"menu image".**

b. go to `admin->category` Now upload images in **menu image** as per your requirements.

c. You can get that image in your menu phtml file ex: `<?php $category->getMenuImage() ?>`

d. You need to customize html to set image above your menu. Design menu like https://snag.gy/iUE8uK.jpg.

e. Now you can add that image anywhere in menu but you need to customize your code and html.

I hope this will help.